# COM equivalent type for C# List

Tags: .net, com

I have a .NET class that I want to expose as COM object. The class as .NET collection type List.

How can .NET collection type be exposed to COM clients ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent. The closest you will get is an array of a specific type.